# Support Dart/Flutter as code snippets

Tags: feature-request, stack-snippets

This is a feature request to extend the "code snippet" feature, to support Dart/Flutter.

These two techs support running on the web ([example](https://dartpad.dev/experimental/embed-new-flutter.html?id=cb8abed13f90a6a0c7a0ada6f15a09c9&theme=dark&split=60)), but are not in JS/HTML and therefore are incompatible with the current "code snippet".

Many of the Flutter questions are about layout/animations, so it would be very valuable to see the output of a code snippet.

It could be something like:

```
<!-- begin snippet: <dart> -->

void main() {
  var list = ['apples', 'bananas', 'oranges'];
  list.forEach((item) {
    print('${list.indexOf(item)}: $item');
  });
}

<!-- end snippet -->
```

Comment: Is Dart/Flutter compiled and run on client side? I remember the company stating at some point that languages which would need to be compiled on their server would add too much load. Unfortunately, I wasn't able to find the duplicate.

Comment: It's server-side. But instead of reinventing the wheel, StackOverflow could just make an iframe on the official dart-pad

Comment: Does the license on dart-pad allow that?

Comment: @rene I suppose? I'm no legal expert. [Here's the license](https://github.com/dart-lang/dart-pad/blob/master/LICENSE). I can contact the team too.

Comment: There are a large number of languages for which runnable snippets would be nice to illustrate problems/solutions quickly, but would have to be run on the backend.

Comment: I'll be more than happy to support this -- [after they update the Stack Snippets to a more recent version of the source script](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/361382/215552)...

Comment: Some members of the Flutter teams admitted that they're considering it https://twitter.com/taodong/status/1165740570716688385.