# Is it possible to embed DartPad into a Stack Overflow post?

Tags: support, stack-snippets

I'm wondering if there is a way to embed [DartPad](https://dart.dev/tools/dartpad) in the Stack Overflow question and answer like mentioned here in the [Embedding Guide](https://github.com/dart-lang/dart-pad/wiki/Embedding-Guide).

I tried to embed but failed, this would be helpful to test code snipped.

```
<iframe style="width:900px;height:600px;" src="https://dartpad.dev/embed-flutter.html?id=0a769a5732d4ec9d6e633dd8ff9690ce&split=80&theme=dark"></iframe>
```

Comment: Support this feature request if you're interested: [Add support for Flutter/Dart code snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/399252/2821954)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm wondering if there is a way to embed DartPad

No, there currently is not.

You can *somewhat* work around that with a Stacks snippet (no whitelisting is applied there). However, you will not be able to use `<iframe>` element to the fullest extent possible as a pretty restrictive `sandbox` attribute set on the `<iframe>` the loaded snippet *itself* is served with.

As of 2021, here is the list of flags enabled on the sandbox:

| Flag | Meaning |
| --- | --- |
| [allow-forms](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/origin.html#attr-iframe-sandbox-allow-forms) | allows forms to be submitted |
| [allow-modals](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/origin.html#attr-iframe-sandbox-allow-modals) | allows usage of `alert`/`prompt`/`confirm`/`print` and the `beforeunload` event |
| [allow-scripts](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/origin.html#attr-iframe-sandbox-allow-scripts) | allows script execution |

Pretty restrictive but mostly sufficient (the commonality of `<iframe>` for web development would make Stack Snippets completely fail at their purpose were they even more restrictive). However this means that some features are not available for security reasons.

Here is a list of what's disallowed in 2021 (not exhaustive, consult the [DOM spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/origin.html#sandboxing) for details):

| Flag | Meaning |
| --- | --- |
| [allow-downloads](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/origin.html#attr-iframe-sandbox-allow-downloads) | initiating downloads of any kind |
| [allow-same-origin](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/origin.html#attr-iframe-sandbox-allow-same-origin) | using `localStorage` and `document.cookie` |
| [allow-pointer-lock](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/origin.html#attr-iframe-sandbox-allow-pointer-lock) | using the Pointer Lock API |

Not being able to use `localStorage` is exactly what DartPad tells you about as [mentioned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/411313/is-it-possible-to-embed-dartpad-into-a-stack-overflow-post#comment865931_411314) by [Zoe](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/6296561/zoe) and as you can see (subject to change in 6 to 8 weeks) from the snippet below:

```html
<iframe style="width:600px;height:600px;" src="https://dartpad.dev/embed-flutter.html?id=0a769a5732d4ec9d6e633dd8ff9690ce&split=80&theme=dark"></iframe>
```

Note the following from the [documentation on embedding](https://dart.dev/tools/dartpad/troubleshoot) DartPad which basically makes even Stack snippets a non-starter:

> Although DartPad doesn’t use cookies, it does **rely on local storage**, which browsers usually disable when cookies are disabled.

Answer (score 4):

That's not possible. `iframe` elements [aren't whitelisted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites) in SO's markdown editor.

Furthermore, it's not likely SE would implement functionality like this in the editor / stack snippets, as the code would have to be run server-side, which would be a significant investment for relatively little gain.

Comment: Would putting the `<iframe>` into a stack snippet not work?

Comment: I assume the same whitelist applies, @WaiHaLee

Comment: It doesn't. Snippets don't have a whitelist or a blacklist (AFAIK), and iframes work. That said, the site errors out with "DartPad requires localStorage to be enabled. For more information, visit dart.dev/tools/dartpad/troubleshoot." (for the record, works fine if I visit the link in a proper tab), and the entire window is _tiny_ even if it did work.